# M2 REST API: Creating shipment with products from MSI source

Tags: magento2.3, rest-api, shipment, msi

I am using MSI.

When trying to create a shipment with a source code, the shipment uses the "default source" instead of the one I'm providing.

My Request:
[POST] /rest/default/V1/order/5/ship

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "order_item_id": 14,
            "qty": 1
        }
    ],
    "extension_attributes" : {
        "source_code" : "3"
    }
}
```

I've used this documentation to create my request:
https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_23.html#/salesShipmentRepositoryV1/salesShipmentRepositoryV1SavePost

The source "3" has sufficient stock, so this shouldn't be the issue

- When "default source" has stock, the shipment is created uses stock from "default source"
- When "default source" has no stock, I get the following: `Shipment Document Validation Error(s):\nThe order does not allow a shipment to be created.\nYou can't create a shipment without products.`

So it definitely tries to use the default source, which is what I don't want.

**My question:**
How can I tell Magento to use my source code? Do I need to provide the source code in a different way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue lies in the JSON structure. You should use `arguments.extension_attributes.source_code`, instead of `extension_attributes.source_code` as shown below:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "order_item_id": 14,
            "qty": 1
        }
    ],
    "arguments": {
        "extension_attributes" : {
            "source_code" : "3"
        }
    }
}
```

Then, it will create the shipment (using the specified source) and return the `shipment_id` as the response.

I have tested this in Magento 2.3.2-p2

Answer (score 2):

I think you pass the wrong source code.

```
"source_code" : "3"
```

If you open the following class:

> vendor/magento/module-inventory-shipping/Plugin/Sales/Shipment/AssignSourceCodeToShipmentPlugin.php

Following code snippet resolve correct source:

```
if (empty($sourceCode)) {
    $websiteId = $order->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
    $stockId = $this->stockByWebsiteIdResolver->execute((int)$websiteId)->getStockId();
    $sources = $this->getSourcesAssignedToStockOrderedByPriority->execute((int)$stockId);
    //TODO: need ro rebuild this logic | create separate service
    if (!empty($sources) && count($sources) == 1) {
        $sourceCode = $sources[0]->getSourceCode();
    } else {
        $sourceCode = $this->defaultSourceProvider->getCode();
    }
}
```

So following code returns nothing and tried from the default source.

> $sources =
>   $this->getSourcesAssignedToStockOrderedByPriority->execute((int)$stockId);

Comment: Good to know Sohel! This helped me find my issue, as specified in my own answer. It had to do with how I structured my JSON request

Answer (score 0):

This post is in top searches for the following error:

```
Shipment Document Validation Error(s):
The order does not allow a shipment to be created.
You can't create a shipment without products.
```

So I'll add my experience which in my case was because, Magento 2 has a designed flaw (in my humble opinion).

I needed to be able to push `partial-shipping` and I was going crazy by trying to push the simple product Id (logically thinking - I don't see how there can be any other option).
But, every time I was getting the same upper error.

I was creating the shipment by submitting the data to following url (POST) [(magento wiki)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/tutorials/orders/order-create-shipment.html):

```
https://www.{domain.co.uk}/index.php/rest/{store_code}/V1/order/{order_id}/ship
```

This was the submitted data:

```
{
    "appendComment": 1,
    "comment": {
        "comment": "Shipment created via API",
        "is_visible_on_front": 1
    },
  "items": [
    {
      "order_item_id": 369,
      "qty": 1
    }
  ],
  "notify": 1,
  "tracks": [
    {
      "track_number": "54149997365",
      "title": "Shipment 1300000010",
      "carrier_code": "DHL"
    }
  ]
}
```

This line was the one creating all the trouble:

```
"order_item_id": 369,
```

`369` - is the Item_ID for `simple product` while Magento is waiting the `configurable` Item_id which in my case was:

```
368
```

So, magento is expecting the `configurable` order item id and NOT the `simple product` item id.

I just have one question: why Magento? WHYY??
Never-mind the fact you force in URL to use the internal `order_id` and not the `incremental_id` but using the configurable instead of `simple product` :( ?!?

P.S. Another reason for the same error is: if the shipment already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue. In my case, the root cause was completely wrong order_item_id

**NOTICE**
order_item_id **IS NOT EQUAL** product_id

You can get order_item_id for example with request rest/all/V1/orders/{order_id}